# Чи застаріло слово респектабельний?

Tags: стилістика

В Академічному тлумачному словнику (1970—1980) слово *респектабельний* наводиться з зауваженням *застаріле*. В Українсько-російському словнику під ред.І. М. Кириченко. (1953–196) - *застаріле, іронічне*. Чи в сучасній мовній практиці таке стилістичне маркування залишається актуальним?

Comment: Воно недоцїльне через чуженаростка _‑абельниь_ від _‑able_.

Comment: тоді слово комфортабельний також недоцільно вживати

Comment: Обережно з коментарями та відповідями пана Follower'a, він у нас тут знаний експериментатор з формою та змістом. Можна заплутатися) Але це жодним чином не нівелює академічних здібностей цього дописувача)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цікаво, що словник подає респектабельний в якості додатка до слів на позначення особи. В такому випадку нема підстав сумніватися, що слово застаріле. Респектабельних розвідників, респектабельних офіцерів чи навіть респектабельну людину в джерелах знайти важко. Знайшовся приклад статті "[Що означає бути респектабельним?](https://www.rbc.ua/ukr/digests/chto-znachit-byt-respektabelnym--19082013172800)", та окрім мовних помилок (машинний переклад?) сам зміст викликає лиш посмішку.

Інша річ, що копірайтери повернули це слово в ролі додатка до назв неосіб, і це вже справжнє люте кліше. Я кажу про всі ті респектабельні готелі, респектабельний відпочинок, через що різні журналісти й автори підхопили слово і пишуть таке:

[Латвія - респектабельний офшор нового типу для легальних капіталів.](http://offshore-express.com.ua/uk/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/rietumu-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BD.htm)

[Відтепер респектабельний французький тлумачний словник Le Petit Robert містить такі вислови, як "lol" та "біопік".](https://www.ukrinform.ua/rubric-world/1366601-respektabelniy_frantsuzkiy_tlumachniy_slovnik_znatime_slovo_lol_1736383.html)

Важко сказати, чи це тепер означає **гідний**, чи **солідний**, чи **поважний**, а чи все разом із якимось обертоном іронії. Але точно, що слово стало із присмаком шаблонної реклами.